# How to make frame[t] as global default?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

In Beamer, I would like to set `frame[t]{ ... }` as a global default of `frame`.

How is it possible to set the option `t` as default?

p.s. I know that it is possible by defining my custom command like `framet{ ... }` with `\renewcommand`. But I'm looking for another way which achieve it without modifying the name of command `frame`, because I'm using LyX.

```
\documentclass[english,dvipdfmx]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Sample Frame 1}
Normally, the text is placed in the middle (default).
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Sample Frame 2}
If you set the option `t' to the frame command, the text is placed at the top.
I would like make this as default.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post an example document? Makes answering less hazardous (and, therefore, more likely).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass the `[t]` option to the class like

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
```

so that all frames are `t`op aligned. If any frame needs to be center aligned then use `\begin{frame}[c]` (or `[b]` for `b`ottom alignment) to that single frame.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Some text
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    Again some more
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]